# How can this code corrupt my stack trace?

Tags: c, gdb

This simple test program,

```
$ cat crash.c 
int main() {
    int x = 0;
    *(&x + 5) = 10;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with GCC 7.4.0,

```
$ gcc -O0 -g crash.c
```

Has an unexpected stack trace

```
$ ./a.out 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ gdb ./a.out /tmp/wk_cores/core-pid_19675.dump
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
[New LWP 19675]
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f450000000a in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f450000000a in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007fffd6f97598 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000100008000 in ?? ()
#4  0x00005632be83d66a in frame_dummy ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

I don't understand why the stack doesn't show the invalid store to privileged memory? Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: Which invalid store to privileged memory?

Comment: `*(&x + 5) = 10;` causes undefined behavior, so it is likely corrupting a stack pointer. It needs those stack pointers to correctly perform the stack trace.

Comment: Actual OS's actuate some stack protection strategies that could sort of shield  it from small out of bound accesses.

Comment: Assuming that your addresses are 64 bit, but integer only takes 32 bits, the lower half of `0x00007f450000000a` might be caused by your invalid assignment.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why the stack doesn't show the invalid store to privileged memory?

Because you *didn't* store anything to privileged memory.

To do that, you need to write *way* outside of stack, something like:

```
*(&x + 0x10000) = 5;
```

As is, your program does exhibit undefined behavior, but it doesn't write to "privileged" memory, just to memory that is writable, but that you should't write to.

Answer (score -1):

x is the latest variable in your stack. So if you write at x+5, *no matter how far you go*, you always write in stack memory after the region of the current allocated stack. Therefore it always fail.

Comment: This answer makes no sense *at all*.

Comment: I was about to comment something like "add a buffer after the declaration of x". I wanted to explain that if you write past the last adress of something allocated on the stack, then (bruh) you will *always* write outside the stack, which *always* give you segfaulf because reading unallocated memory. However this trick doesn't work because modern compilers can detect what gcc call "stack smashing".